# Is threadpools okay for production? If not, is there any alternative libraries?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am porting some Java code to C++ and wanted to find something that worked like Java's `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  I saw a few posts suggesting [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) but after reading a few other forums I have read about problems([memory leaks](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/56971/), etc..) and browsing the [code base](http://threadpool.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/threadpool/threadpool/) I see the last update was over 3 years ago.  So my problem is, I'm not quite up to speed to make my own thread-pool library but I don't want to use something that is not actively maintained.

Upon looking around there's a few threadpool projects but they don't seem heavily used(I'm basing it on how family favorites/watches on github/code.google).  I was wondering what other people are using for threadpools in production environments?  I'm looking for 2 types of thread-pools, one fixed and one that grows dynamically.

Comment: Intel have their Thread Building Blocks library, so that would probably be a safe bet in terms of the code-base being maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which platform ? If windows and can use [ppl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx) using Visual C++ compiler, then take
a look at `task_group` and `make_task` methods to create tasks. [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) is
another option.

If you can use boost, then [boost concurrent programming APIs](https://github.com/boost-vault/Concurrent-Programming)
can be useful.